# Why won't GTA V launch?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

When I launch GTA V from Steam, this appears:

[image: screenshot of error message - text below]

<sup>"Grand Theft Auto V Launcher has stopped working. Windows can check online for a solution to the problem."</sup>

I have played GTA on this computer for many hours before, and I have never had this problem. I have tried restarting my computer, but nothing changes.

Comment: I realized that it's a bit hard to see the picture. It says: Grand Theft Auto V Launcher has stopped working. Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.

Comment: Are you on a desktop PC or a laptop? What's your GPU?

Comment: @Chippies I'm on a desktop PC and my GPU is a AMD Radeon HD 7900

Comment: Have you done anything major since the last time you played it? Like update drivers or install some updates or something?

Comment: Try verifying file integrity in steam, you may have corrupted some files.

Comment: @Chippies I don't know what I did to corrupt the files, but vertifying the file integrity worked. Thanks a lot. You have helped me on multiple posts :) I don't understand how you know everything

Comment: File corruption can happen for various reasons, doesn't mean you did anything to cause it. I posted an answer, so you can mark this question as answered. :)

Comment: Did you install any mods? (That could case the GTA V files' integrity to be corrupted.) Also, do a `chkdsk` run (with bad sector scanning) of your system,  to check if it's an issue with your hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible cause could be corrupt files. Verifying file integrity in Steam would fix it, if that's the case.

File corruption could happen for various reasons, like computer shutting down at the wrong time or an error while downloading game update, among many other things.